# Is there a way to emphasize on a single word of a phrase in google search

Tags: seo, html, google-search, search-results

Example if I am searching

"How to enable a google chrome extension only in incognito mode"

It shows results from

"How to enable a google chrome extension in incognito mode"

Obviously this is not what I wanted and I want to emphasize on '**only**' Is there any advanced search filter for that.

I did lot of research, and from a webmasters point of you using `<strong><b><em>` tag must be used while writing content, i.e., if I am writing a blog about the same topic I must write it like

```
<h1>How to enable a google chrome extension <em>only</em> in incognito mode</h1>
```

I don't know how much of it is a fact ergo I need some assistance.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if using a tag like `<em>` around a keyword in your source code would result in Google more likely to return results with that keyword when phrases are searched?

Comment: To support what @dan has said, very few tags actually get attention or have a special trigger- the em tag is one of these. However, bold, italics, and strong do not do anything at all. SEO advice on this is based upon bad blackbox testing. To be fair, there was a point where weighting on terms that were bold or italics were weighted a slight bit heavier in the semantic link map, but that proved to have no value in matching search intent. This weighting lasted a very short period and was only slight in the first place. Semantics, in the end, works best with a simpler schema.

Comment: This sounds like a webapps question, not a webmastering one. No matter how you mark up your page, you're not going to influence what Google actually searches for (or not) when entering a particular search phrase.

Answer (score 2):

You can force Google to look for a word by putting it in quotes:

```
"only" in incognito
```

“Only”, however, is a very general word, so that won’t work. Instead, you need to build larger groups and force Google to search for them literally:

```
"only in incognito"
```

You’ll want to make these as short as possible, because there are many ways to write stuff that means the same.

You’re also better off if you leave out unnecessary filler words. Google doesn’t understand sentences, it uses keywords.

```
 chrome extension enable "only in incognito"
```

That being said, this is probably off-topic anyway.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to do this from the website side of things, not when you're running the search yourself.